# Pourquoi le pluriel « allers-retours » est-il controversé ?

Tags: pluriel, noms, mots-composés

Le nom composé « aller-retour » est composé de deux noms et son pluriel est sémantiquement le pluriel des deux composantes. Il serait donc logique que son pluriel consiste à mettre les deux composantes au pluriel : « allers-retours ». (Note : aller-retour reste au singulier — de fait invariable — lorsqu'il est utilisé en apposition : « deux trajets aller-retour » ; ma question porte sur son usage en tant qu'épithète au pluriel.)

Or certaines sources recommandent de laisser « aller-retour » invariable : [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller-retour) cite par exemple le *Dictionnaire Bordas des pièges et difficultés de la langue française*. L'Académie française recommanderait *allers-retours* (je n'ai pas trouvé la référence). La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3915) québecoise déclare le pluriel *allers-retours* comme logique tout en signalant l'invariabilité comme un usage minoritaire. À l'usage, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+allers-retours%2Cdes+aller-retour%2Cdes+aller-retours&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20allers%20-%20retours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20aller%20-%20retour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20aller%20-%20retours%3B%2Cc0) donne « des allers-retours » nettement majoritaire, mais l'on trouve aussi « des aller-retour » et même « des aller-retours ».

Pourquoi « aller-retour » serait-il invariable ? Cela tient-il au mot lui-même où est-ce corrélé à rendre d'autres mots composés invariables ?

Comment: [Voici](http://sophie-viguier-correctrice.e-monsite.com/pages/mes-orthotrucs/les-ortho-trucs-precedents/orthographe/des-aller-retour-ou-des-allers-retours.html) ce qu'en dit une correctrice professionnelle qui cite le *Dictionnaire d’orthographe* (André Jouette, Le Robert, 2003).  Et le [P'tit Dico du Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/a-la-une/article_interactif/2005/05/20/le-p-tit-dico_651885_3208_1.html) dit aussi allers-retours sans donner de source.

Comment: D'après [ce forum](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic22089-plurier-de-aller-et-retour.html) Grevisse donne allers-retours (mais mon exemplaire, édition probablement trop ancienne ne comporte pas l'exemple cité). Et pour [orthonet](http://orthonet.sdv.fr/php/rech_mot.php?mot=ale) c'est allers-retours sans autre forme de procès.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, §528 a)) se place fermement dans le camp de la variabilité, car le composé est dans la catégories des composés coordonnés (cf. l'étymologie *aller et retour*). Je crois que l'invariabilité (partielle ou complète) qui persiste chez certains auteurs est due à deux facteurs distinct:

- *aller* dans un usage variable est une construction relativement récente au départ, ce qui suscite toujours une certaine réaction d'opposition (la plupart des infinitifs variables sont beaucoup plus anciens ou rarement utilisés dans des constructions plurielles)
- *aller-retour* peut êre senti comme une ellipse de *trajet* ou *billet aller-retour*, constructions où il n'y a pas de variabilité.